# IdentityServer4 - How to custom Refresh token lifetime for each user with the same client?

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

My context is users use the same client_id, all property of the client is the same with all users but *RefreshToken*.

So, how can I custom *RefreshToken* for each user with the same client?

I tried to use `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` but  only custom *AccessToken* (or not found the right way)

```
public class CustomTokenRequestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
   public async Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
   {
     var request = context.Result.ValidatedRequest;
     var refreshToken = request.RefreshToken; // always null when call to /connect/token
     // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The RefreshToken should be different for each user which logs in. You can configure the RefreshToken with following properties: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html

Comment: Your client needs the offline_access scope to get the refresh token

Comment: I need to set the AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime different for each user. Can I set by this way?
request.Client.RefreshTokenExpiration = IdentityServer4.Models.TokenExpiration.Absolute;
request.Client.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = xxx;